# Website preview for a wordPress based site on a development server

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel

I have created a demo website for a client. I installed the site on the client's live domain name and I used the etc/host DNS trick to point the domain to my development sever. Now I want to send a live preview to client for validation but I don't want to bother her with technical details such as modifying local computer host file. The client doesn’t want to switch the domain to the new site either, until everything is ready as the site is highly active. I have tried the cpanel temporary link (mod_userdir is enabled) but it breaks everything including styles and scripts. Do you have any solution. Thanks.
Update: I have found this site if it can help [nodns.io](http://nodns.io/), they only need the emulated domain name and the development server IP.

Comment: Is it an option to use a subdomain? Like dev.yoururl.com? You can install a copy of wordpress in a separate directory and let this subdomain point to that installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the temporary URL and that is the easiest way. You just need to make a change in the WordPress database. You can go to cPanel -> phpMyAdmin, open the database and look for the _options table.

Once you find it, you need to change the home and siteurl options to the temporary URL:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

You can follow the "Changing the URL directly in the database" directions.

Goodluck!